# Why should a self-implemented getter retain and autorelease the returned object?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uikit

Example:

```
- (NSString*) title {
    return [[title retain] autorelease];
}
```

The setter actually retained it already, right? and actually nobody should bypass the Setter... so I wonder why the getter not just returns the object? It's actually retained already. Or would this just be needed in case that in the mean time another objects gets passed to the setter?

Answer (score 12):

From here http://www.macosxguru.net/article.php?story=20030713184140267

```
- (id)getMyInstance
    {
        return myInstanceVar ;
    }
```

or

```
- (id)getMyInstance
{
    return [[myInstanceVar retain] autorelease] ;
}
```

What's the difference ?
The second one allows the caller to get an instance variable of a container object, dispose of the container and continue to play with the instance variable until the next release of the current autoreleased pool, without being hurt by the release of the instance variable indirectly generated by the release of its container:

```
aLocalVar = [aContainer getAnInstanceVar] ;
[aContainer release];
doSomething(aLocalVar);
```

If the "get" is implemented in the first form, you should write:

```
aLocalVar = [[aContainer getAnInstanceVar] retain];
[aContainer release];
doSomething(aLocalVar);
[aLovalVar release];
```

The first form is a little bit more efficent in term of code execution speed.
However, if you are writing frameworks to be used by others, maybe the second version should be recommanded: it makes life a little bit easier to people using your framework: they don't have to think too much about what they are doing…;)
If you choose the first style version, state it clearly in your documentation… Whatever way you will be choosing, remember that changing from version 1 to version 2 is save for client code, when going back from version 2 to version 1 will break existing client code…

Answer (score 7):

It's not just for cases where someone releases the container, since in that case it's more obvious that they should retain the object themselves. Consider this code:

```
NSString* newValue = @"new";
NSString* oldValue = [foo someStringValue];
[foo setSomeStringValue:newValue];
// Go on to do something with oldValue
```

This looks reasonable, but if neither the setter nor the getter uses autorelease the "Go on to do something" part will likely crash, because oldValue has now been deallocated (assuming nobody else had retained it). You usually want to use Technique 1 or Technique 2 from [Apple's accessor method examples](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAccessorMethods.html) so code like the above will work as most people will expect.

Answer (score 4):

Compare this code

```
  return [[title retain] release]; // releases immediately
```

with this

```
  return [[title retain] autorelease]; // releases at end of current run loop (or if autorelease pool is drained earlier)
```

The second one guarantees that a client will have a non-dealloced object to work with.

This can be useful in a situation like this (client code):

```
 NSString *thing = [obj title];
 [obj setTitle:nil]; // here you could hit retainCount 0!
 NSLog(@"Length %d", [thing length]); // here thing might be dealloced already!
```

**The retain (and use of `autorelease` instead of `release`) in your `title` method prevents this code from blowing up.** The autoreleased object will not have its `release` method called until AFTER the current call stack is done executing (end of the current run loop). This gives all **client** code in the call stack a chance to use this object without worrying about it getting dealloc'ed.

**The Important Thing To Remember:** This ain't Java, Ruby or PHP. Just because you have a reference to an object in yer [sic] variable does NOT ensure that you won't get it dealloc'ed from under you. You have to retain it, but **then you'd have to remember to release it.** Autorelease lets you avoid this. You should **always** use autorelease unless you're dealing with properties or loops with many iterations (and probably not even then unless a problem occurs).

Comment: Also see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816898/methods-that-call-methods-basics-of-autorelease

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this pattern before, but it seems fairly pointless to me. I guess the intent is to keep the returned value safe if the client code calls "release" on the parent object. It doesn't really hurt anything, but I doubt that situation comes up all that often in well-designed libraries.

---

Ah, ok. from the documentation smorgan linked to, it seems this is now one of the methods that Apple is currently recommending that people use. I think I still prefer the old-school version:

```
- (NSString *) value
{
    return myValue;
}

- (void) setValue: (NSString *) newValue
{
    if (newValue != myValue)
    {
       [myValue autorelease]; // actually, I nearly always use 'release' here
       myValue = [newValue retain];
    }
}
```

Comment: That depends. It’s an absolute requirement for properties that may be accessed from multiple threads, for instance. More generally, situations that don’t come up often are the ones that lead to really annoying head-scratchers.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying, with regards to multiple threads, since you could then have multiple independent release pools and run loops. I still think autorelease in the setter makes more sense in that case.

Comment: And in the case of multi-threaded access, I usually use [obj copy] - having separate instances of objects eliminates any chance of conflict.

Comment: If you use `[obj copy]` then you have an extra retain on the obj you're sending back. Who will release it? So you end up doing `[[obj copy] autorelease]` which is the same. Just returning `myValue` (the old-school version) is safe until it isn't, like sea-level power generators.