# objective c memory leak in Apple documention?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm just learning Objective C, so I'm probably missing something, but the below code is a leak, right?

Taken from [apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003539-SW6):

```
- (NSString*) title {
    return [[title retain] autorelease];
}

- (void) setTitle: (NSString*) newTitle {
    if (title != newTitle) {
        [title release];
        title = [newTitle retain]; // Or copy, depending on your needs.
    }
}
```

The getter retains and autoreleases (cancelling each other out), but the setter retains also. That stops the reference count from ever reaching 0, right? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing (because it's not shown in the example) is that there will be a `release` for all retained properties in the object's `dealloc` method.

Comment: so, why not just return title from the getter? Meaning, eliminate the retain/autorelease?

Comment: nevermind, answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801828/why-should-a-self-implemented-getter-retain-and-autorelease-the-returned-object

Answer (score 0):

Ah, if I had read farther in the documentation, Apple explains:

> Because the object returned from the get accessor is autoreleased in the current scope, it remains valid if the property value is changed

retain/autorelease is useful when the setter is called after the getter, since the setter releases the old value.