# Converting NSImage to NSData

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, image, cocoa

I get NSImage like that:

```
imageG = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(imageN.size.width, imageN.size.height)] autorelease];
[imageG addRepresentation:[NSCIImageRep imageRepWithCIImage:result]];
```

And the result is really good. So there are no mistakes i think. And then I try to convert this image to NSData like that:

```
 NSData *imgData = [imageG TIFFRepresentation];
```

And i am getting error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=13, adress=0x0)
```

at that line. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **need to `retain` your object** as you create it, it appears it's being reallocated by the time you ask it for its data reorientation.

`imageG = [[[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(imageN.size.width, imageN.size.height)] retain] autorelease];`

Generally if you create an object from an initializer - not a factory method - you should retain and auto release it. The benefits of doing so, and other good tips on memory management can be found at: [Why should a self-implemented getter retain and autorelease the returned object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801828/why-should-a-self-implemented-getter-retain-and-autorelease-the-returned)

It's also to handy to note that `BAD_ACCESS` indicates a memory issue of some kind.